# Check if timestamp is today using SQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I've seen some questions that asked about it, but nothing helped me.

I have a column named `timestamp`, and inside it there is a timestamp value, that says when it inserted. for example: `1366030060`.

I want to select only the rows that inserted today.
I'm using Mysql

This is my code: (I added the WHERE and it's not working)

```
        SELECT      `chat`.`message`,
                    `chat`.`timestamp`,
                    `users`.`username`,
                    `users`.`id`
        FROM        `chat`
        JOIN        `users`
        ON          `chat`.`userid` = `users`.`id`
        WHERE       `chat`.`timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
        ORDER BY    `chat`.`timestamp`
        DESC
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT colList
FROM tbl
WHERE timestampCol >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
```

Comment: I added your code and it's not working, it returns an empty mysqli error. What is the problem? (I edited my question)

Comment: I added at the end of the query: `or die('<script>console.log("'.$this->db->error.'")</script>');` And it returns empty error

Comment: I don't know what that is. It's not part of the question. The code works fine [in this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d022/1).

Comment: My sql code works fine without your line. So maybe I puted it in wrong place or something ?

Comment: @ArielAharonson What is the column type of `timestamp`

Comment: int............(sorry for the dottes, the comment must be at least 15 characters)

Comment: Do you even have any records that are greater than today's date? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chat WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())`

Comment: Of course, I even tried to turn the sign, to make sure that the problem is a logical problem.

Comment: @ArielAharonson So how many records are returned from that `COUNT` query?

Comment: OK. I truncated the table, and inserted the rows again, and now it works, thanks god! I don't know what was the problem, but now it works!! Thanks you so much!!! and sorry for the trouble...